# Giving error unexpected token: 'where' at line 13 column 281

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am getting this error

> unexpected token: 'where' at line 13 column 281

```
public with sharing class Form_Salgsplakat_Bilpris {
 dealer__Vehicle_Inventory__c vi =new dealer__Vehicle_Inventory__c();

public dealer__Vehicle_Inventory__c getvi()
{
    return vi;
}

        public Form_Salgsplakat_Bilpris(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
        {
           // Deal id
           // Slect vehicleID from RelatedLook wher deal = "pagId" limit 1;
        vi=[Select id,Name,Brand__c,Description_salesprospect__c,dealer__Exterior_Color__c,dealer__Interior_Color__c,dealer__Stock_Number__c,Engine_Displacement_CC__c,Horsepower__c,dealer__Max_Torque__c,Dry_weight_kg__c,Extra_urban__c,CO2_emissions_g_km__c,dealer__Mileage__c from where id IN:[select id,Name,dealer__Vehicle__c from dealer__Deal__c where dealer__Vehicle__c IN:controller.getRecord().id]LIMIT 1];

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs to include the object to query, you have

```
ler__Mileage__c from where id IN:[select id,N
```

needs to be

```
ler__Mileage__c from <InsertSObjectName> where id IN:[select id,N
```